# Returning Byte Array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, wcf, byte

I have the following function (in a WCF)

```
Public Function GetPDF_Byte() As Byte Implements IService1.GetPDF_Byte
    Dim fs As New FileStream("C:\My.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim ImageData As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}

    fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))

    fs.Close()

    Return ImageData


End Function
```

Problem is, I'm getting the following error on 'Return ImageData':

```
Value of type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to 'Byte'.
```

I've been playing with it, but can't seem to figure out what I need to do to ImageData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function needs to return byte array:

```
Public Function GetPDF_Byte() As Byte()
```

So either the method in the interface and class is defined as `Byte` and needs to be changed to byte array or it must be indeed byte and you need to return a single byte - which I really doubt as it is image data.